# Taylor Series Expansion of $\frac{\cos(2z)}{e^z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How might I got about finding the radius of convergence of $\frac{\cos(2z)}{e^z+1}$ based on its Taylor expansion?  I know that in simple cases the ratio and root test work.  Do those same tests work here with more algebra?  Are there better techniques for this case?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor series with $z_0 = 0$ should converge up to the nearest singularity. There are two nearest singularities, $\pm i \pi$, whose distance from $z_0$ is $\pi$, so
$$
\rho = \pi
$$

Comment: Is this only true for $z_0 = 0$?  Why is this true (for $z_0$ or in general)?

Comment: @user73041: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis

Comment: I see, so in our case the distance from the origin is $\pi$ but if $z_0$ was, say, 1, the distance would be something like $\pi-1$?

Comment: So it is then true for $z_0$ generally.  I am still not clear on why it is true but I will read the article more.

Comment: @user73041, no, for $z_0 = 1$ the distance is $|i\pi-1|=\sqrt{1+\pi^2}$

Comment: Right, of course, thank you.